# How to stop 2 buttons from opening the same div tag in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have been working on a comment system in php and jQuery. I am using jQuery to slide a form whenever you press reply but instead 2 buttons work for only one form.

I am using php to get the data from a mysql database and display the content it displays it in div tags with a button that says reply when I click on the second button the first div come's down.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['fname']) && !isset($_SESSION['username']) &&         !isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  echo "<h1>You must be logged in to comment</h1>";
} else { ?>
<div id="comment">
<form action="createcomment.php?videoid=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post">
    Comment: <br /><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-warning">
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="comments">
<?php       $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE videoid = " . $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if(!empty($result)) {
?>
<div class="comment">
<h5><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5>
<p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Reply</button>
<div id="reply">
<form action="replycomment.php?videoid=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&commentid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
    Reply Message: <br /><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Reply" class="btn btn-warning">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php }else {
    echo "<h1>There are no comments.</h1>";
}
}?>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#reply").hide();
$("#comments > div > button").click(function(){
    $("#reply").slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```

The jQuery is supposed to hide all of the reply divs and when you click reply the div opens instead the first button works but the last button opens the first  one i have no idea what is going on.

Thank you.

Comment: id should be unique for entire document

Comment: what is an error you are getting ??

Comment: i don't get a error @santosh

Comment: It's just like @santosh said, it has to do with your id's not being unique. You're generating multiple elements giving them the same ID.

Comment: but how do i fix that when its coming from a mysql database

Comment: I don't see how the PHP is relevant to your question. Post the rendered HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There can only be one of each ID in the entire DOM.** You have an element with the id of "reply". Since the database is looping through all of the comments, there will be multiple elements with the id of "reply". **This syntax is not correct.**

Now, if you click on a button to toggle the element with the id of "reply", all of them will toggle. That's not what you want. Change the HTML to:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Reply</button>
<div class="reply">
  <form action="replycomment.php?videoid=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&commentid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
    Reply Message: <br /><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Reply" class="btn btn-warning">
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that I have removed the id, and added the class. **There can be multiple classes in a DOM.** And so, the jQuery needs to hide all of the classes, so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".reply").hide();
  // Hides all the elements with class="reply"
});
```

Now all we need is the button click action. If we just change the hashtag to the dot and make it a class, it still will toggle ALL of the elements with the class of reply. We need to just toggle the element that is right after the clicked button... right?

And so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#comments > div > button").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.reply:first').slideToggle();
    // Gets all the next sibling elements under the same parent, and selects the first one with the class="reply"
  });
});
```